# How can we check if local Object exist in test script developed in QTP through vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, automation, qtp, hp-uft

Suppose I have a Test script developed in qtp,and now my requirement is to check whether this particular test case has a local Object associated with it through VBscript??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below funciton in VBScript can check if the current test has an object with a particular name in its Object Repository.

```
Function CheckIfObjectPresentInOR(ByVal LogicalName)
    Set ObjectRepositoryUtil =  CreateObject("Mercury.ObjectRepositoryUtil") 
    ObjectRepositoryUtil.Load "<Path of the Object Repository>"
    Set TOCOllection = ObjectRepositoryUtil.GetAllObjects
    booFunctionStatus = FALSE
    For i = 0 To TOCollection.Count - 1 
            If ObjectRepositoryUtil.GetLogicalName(TOCOllection.Item(i)) = LogicalName Then
                    booFunctionStatus = TRUE
                    Exit For
            End If
    Next
    Set ObjectRepositoryUtil =  Nothing
    Set TOCOllection = Nothing
    CheckIfObjectPresentInOR = booFunctionStatus
End Function
```

EDIT:

```
Function CheckIfObjectPresentInOR
    Set ObjectRepositoryUtil =  CreateObject("Mercury.ObjectRepositoryUtil") 
    ObjectRepositoryUtil.Load "<Path of the Object Repository>"
    booFunctionStatus = FALSE
    Set TOCOllection = ObjectRepositoryUtil.GetAllObjects
    If TOCOllection.Count > 0 Then
         booFunctionStatus  = TRUE
    End If
    Set ObjectRepositoryUtil =  Nothing
    Set TOCOllection = Nothing
    CheckIfObjectPresentInOR = booFunctionStatus
End Function
```

Comment: This code will work but my requirement is slightly different,user didnt know the name of Object.I mean,I just want to know whether there is any Object inside local object repository.Just want to get the boolean result either 'true' or 'false'.Condition is that I am unaware of 'Local Repository' of the test case and I dont want to see it manually i want to check this through my code.Is there any way to do so??

Comment: Check the EDIT. It just gives if any object is present in the local object repository. local object repository path is \<testname>\<actionname>\objectrepository.bdp

Comment: I tried to use this code but its showing 'general error' at the line when I am giving path of local object repository.Can u tell what is wrong?Is the name of the local repository is correct?

Comment: I got it.The name of Local or is "ObjectRepository.bdb".This code is exactly as I needed.Thanks Bro :)